# In a shader, what is the meaning of l()?

Tags: shaders, hlsl

For instance, `l(2.000000)` or `l(1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)`. This is in HLSL.

Example in use:

```
mad r0.z, r0.y, l(-2.000000), l(3.000000)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that it's most likely loading the scalar value into an appropriate register, but my Google-fu is failing to find this mentioned in any documentation...

Comment: What can you tell us about where you've encountered this l()? Is this assembly generated from a shader that you wrote? If so, show us the source code that replicates this assembly, and what tool/version you're using to compile it yo get this result. If this is in a shader you've found, try linking us to the source where you found it.